# CSS - computed style over declared style

Tags: html, css, extjs

I made an application in ExtJS 6, a have made a menu and made the menu items as links. The colors changed to the default link colors, so I wanted to change them to black. I wrote a CSS and it works it loads, in Chrome in the Elements panel in Styles menu it shows that it's the active style. But when I check the Computed menu, it shows me that color is rgb(85, 26, 139). I can even expand it, where it shows me this:

[image]

The css which contains the styling is added last, I tried almost everything which comes in my mind.
Something should be with the hyperlinks, because there are some menu items which arent used as links and the styling works on them well.

Any idea what can I do with it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

My css style:

```
.menu-item a:link, .menuItem a:visited, .menuItem a:hover, .menuItem a:active {
    color: #222222 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, so your styling works, but the chrome inspector shows the wrong one?

Comment: No, in browser it's still also with the default colors and in Computed. But in Styles it shows me that my style is active. - And aslo as you can see on the picture when I expand the computed styles there is nothing about that purple color.

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe it's overwritten by :active, :focus or :visited. Check the top of the inspector tools for a :hov button inside the styles tab.

Comment: No, its not I edit my question with my styling.

Comment: Does this behaviour happens after you click the link? When you visit a link the :visited property is activated and might be overriding your styling.

Comment: is it `.menu-item` or `.menuItem` ?

Comment: I clicked the menus before I changed the style but I cleared the cache and made a full site refresh, but still when I enter the page the links are colored like this, like they were visited before.

Comment: AA2992: omg, OK you won. First it doesnt applied my styles so I changed some things but it stayed the same, but I haven't seen that I totally messed up my CSS style.

Comment: Happens I guess. I'm not leaving it as an answer. haha. Its a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling the the .menu-item a to #222222; and

.menu-item a:not([href]) { color:rgb(85,26,139);}

```
.menu-item a, .menu-item a:link, .menuItem a:visited, .menuItem a:hover, .menuItem a:active {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-item a:not([href]) {
  color:rgb(85,26,139);
}
```

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Harvey89/164opbL4/3/

Probably best not to use !important

Comment: No, as you can see it above in the comments I tried so hard that I made some typo.